# cannot find symbol intellij gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

This seemingly very simple or even silly question has been bothering me.

What I did:

1. On my fresh new Mac OS X 10.13.6
2. I used Intellij CE 2018.1 version to check out a repo from Github.
3. Whenever I tried to run unit tests in this repo from my Intellij, it simply says: "Cannot find symbol", screenshot below:
   [image]
4. I didn't make any changes locally, this is a build green project that I checked out from a git repo.
5. this is build.gradle file

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

   group = 'com.fishercoder'
   version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

   checkstyle {
      //include ( '**/*.java')
      configFile = file("${rootDir}/fishercoder_checkstyle.xml")
   }

   description = """"""

   sourceCompatibility = 1.9
   targetCompatibility = 1.9

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
       testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
   }
   ```

What I've tried:

1. Interestingly, I could print out a "Hello world" in ***src*** code part, but ***tst*** part just don't compile in Intellij.
2. I've invalidated caches and restart my Intelij, no luck.
3. I've removed the folder on my disk, completely shutdown my Intellij, redo git clone into my disk first, then open Intellij to import it, see below:
   [image]

Then imported it as a gradle project, see below:
[image]

Left everything on the following page as default:
[image]

Then in my Intellij console, I got this error:
[image]
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you import the project as a gradle project in IDEA?

Comment: Open Gradle Tool window and refresh the project (hit the circular button at the top).

Comment: @abdul Yes, I've tried that, no luck.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman Thanks for reminding me that. I just did it and I'll update my original post.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you are importing the project, Gradle wrapper is choosing an incompatible version of Gradle for JDK 10 ([See This](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4503)).

You can try installing gradle manually in your system (preferably any version that is greater than 4.7). Then choose the option "Use local gradle distribution" and specify the gradle installation path in Intellij.

Then you should be fine!

Comment: I just ran a `gradle --version`, it says `Gradle 4.8.1`

Answer (score 1):

It is not Intellij specific issue of choosing Gradle version. This is as mentioned a [Gradle bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4503) when Gradle can not determine Java version for the 10 JDK. It is fixed in Gradle version >=4.7.

The Gradle error is thrown when IDE tries to run Gradle using the Java 10 JDK. Please use Gradle version >=4.7 in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle -> Use local gradle distribution option. Or use 1.8 JDK for the Gradle JVM.